# How to trigger broadcast receiver after an image is deleted in Gallery?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am working on an android app that is supposed to have copy of deleted image from android gallery. If the user wants to delete a picture from gallery, before he/she delete it, our app must save a copy of the image in a hidden folder.
I used SMS receiver but this one is some thing confusing.

```
       public MyReceiver() {
       }

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //activity which I want to perform here is to have a copy of deleted image in a hidden folder
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You canot track a file when it is deleted. You can use file observer for track other cahnges in a folder.

```
observer = new FileObserver(Your_folder_Path) { // set up a file observer to watch this directory on sd card

 @Override
 public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
     //if(event == FileObserver.CREATE && !file.equals(".probe")){ // check if its a "create" and not equal to .probe because thats created every time camera is launched
     Log.d(TAG, "File created [" + pathToWatch + file + "]");

     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), file + " was saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     //}
 }
};
 observer.startWatching();
```

Comment: can we have path of that image that is to be deleted? Before deleting the image?

Comment: ManzoorHussain:   I am not sure of it. Let me check and get back

Comment: Please @ Cecil Paul

Comment: Observer is the only thing that can observe the changes in the file. But observer will trigger only after the change. In your case it will trigger only after the file is deleted.

Comment: The question can I get uri of the that image after deleted?

Comment: yes. in the above code onEvent will give you string file path.